# Problem processing an array of textareas when they are loaded dynamically with jQuery and PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I am experiencing problems trying to do a multitextarea on a form.

I've a PHP view that has various forms, all processed different but in the same file. They all works, I've tested and they works. In forms there are a + icon that let the user add more instances of a `<textarea />`. This + icon loads via AJAX a new textarea with the same name of the previous textarea (for example, name="example[]"). If I post this, it only gets the first item that is the one that wasn't previously loaded by jQuery. The problem is that the ones loaded dynamically are totally ignored and I don't know why.

My extract of my PHP view:

```
    <?php echo form_open("projects/view/".$projectid); ?> <!-- This generates a valid <form /> tag -->
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th><?php echo lang("label_conx");?></th>
                <td class="textarea-edit">
                    <textarea class="context" name="CONX[]"><?php echo set_value("CONX[]");?></textarea>
                </td>
                <td class="add"><a id="add-conx" href="#"><?php echo img("img/icons/plus.png");?></a></td>
            </tr>
...
```

My jQuery code that works fine because the content is displayed and I see in firebug that is the same as the html loaded textarea:

```
$("a#add-conx").click(function(){
    $("#ajax-loader").fadeIn('normal');

    $("textarea.context:last").after('<textarea class="context" name="CONX[]"></textarea>');

    $("#ajax-loader").fadeOut("normal");

    return false;
});
```

And when I send the form, I've a in my PHP controller `print_r($_POST);` and I only get:

```
Array
(
    [CONX] => Array
        (
            [0] => safdsddasfafsd
        )
    ...
```

If I put on the PHP view various textareas, this array increases as same of the number of textareas I've created on the HTML view file. I don't understand why this is not working.

When the page is load:
[image]

After adding some content dynamically:
[image]

This two images shows 4 instances of textarea with the name context[] 
(that has been changed to CONX[], but fails equal) that are in the view. The second image shows the loaded ones with jQuery and PHP only detected the first 4 that were on the HTML.

Anyone has some idea how I can solve this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is the submit method ? a regular submit or an ajax submit ?

Comment: @Jerome: Its a regular submit but there is like 5 submit buttons for (with different names) in the same page.

Comment: could yu explain it in simple terms

Comment: I'm not hearing anything wrong ... is there any chance you could post a link to a full HTML extract for the form?

Comment: Weird question but is your form tag closed ?

Comment: @Jeff Parker: here: http://pastebin.com/JMUX7xLL thank you in advance!

Comment: @Jerome: you were totally right... I'm sorry... Can you post this an answer and I accept it? Why it worked with HTML code and not with the jQuery loaded? :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect this has something to do with the correctness of your html.

Reading your question and the fact that you use a regular submit the problem could be a missing 'form' end-tag for instance.

Browsers sometimes have weird Javascript behaviors when the html is not properly nested.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the .live() function of jquery.

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: I don't see how that's related ... any chance you could fill in the blanks? :)

Comment: Same... jQuery click don't fails. :)